# Choose row that equal to the max value from a query

Tags: sql-server, count, subquery, max, with-statement

I want to know who has the most friends from the app I own(transactions), which means it can be either he got paid, or paid himself to many other users.

I can't make the query to show me *only* those who have the max friends number (it can be 1 or many, and it can be changed so I can't use limit).

```
;with relationships as 
(
    select
      paid as 'auser',
      Member_No as 'afriend'
    from Payments$
    union all
    select
      member_no as 'auser',
      paid as 'afriend'
    from Payments$
),
DistinctRelationships AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM relationships
)
select
  afriend,
  count(*) cnt
from DistinctRelationShips
GROUP BY
  afriend
order by
  count(*) desc
```

I just can't figure it out, I've tried count, max(count), where = max,  nothing worked.

It's a two columns table - "Member_No" and "Paid" - member pays the money, and the paid is the one who got the money.

| Member_No | Paid |
| --- | --- |
| 14 | 18 |
| 17 | 1 |
| 12 | 20 |
| 12 | 11 |
| 20 | 8 |
| 6 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 9 | 20 |
| 8 | 10 |
| 5 | 20 |
| 14 | 16 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 12 | 1 |
| 14 | 10 |

- It's from Excel, but I loaded it into sql-server.
- It's just a sample, there are 1000 more rows

Comment: Please post sample data along with the required output and not just the SQL query.

Comment: I've posted with it a sample, thanks

Comment: In a CTE add a new column using ROW_NUMBER window function ordered by count DESC then select a record where that column is 1

Comment: @MeirHarel - Please paste it as text, not an image.  Images can't be copied/manipulated or searched.

Comment: I'm just formatting to make it readable, why did you roll it back?

Comment: Sorry Charlieface, other user asked me to post it as a text and not an image.

Comment: The semicolon is a statement terminator. Use it consistently (along with other coding best practices) and you don't need to use this lazy kludge of putting it in front of WITH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are massively over-complicating this. There is no need for self-joining.

Just unpivot each row so you have both sides of the relationship, then group it up by one side and count distinct of the other side

```sql
SELECT
-- for just the first then SELECT TOP (1)
-- for all that tie for the top place use SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
  v.Id,
  Relationships = COUNT(DISTINCT v.Other),
  TotalTransactions = COUNT(*)
FROM Payments$ p
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    (p.Member_No, p.Paid),
    (p.Paid, p.Member_No)
) v(Id, Other)
GROUP BY
  v.Id
ORDER BY
  COUNT(DISTINCT v.Other) DESC;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e8a07dc8ddb878ead069e2de2126d714)

Comment: Thanks! It's simpler that what I've done, but it doesn't show max, it shows desc. can you show me how it can select only those who have the max friends vakue (can be 1 person or many users)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Surely the top row is the max? Can you add expected results to your question please